# Unit test class constructor and method with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to figure out how to perform unit tests, with Jest, on my code but I have been struggling with this. I want to be able to test the constructor and the method in my unit test but I can't understand how to do it in an efficient way.

```js
class CommandOption {
  constructor(commands) {
    this.section = commands[0]
    this.method = commands[1]
    this.command1 = commands[2]
  }

  option(optionName) {
    return require(`../commands/options/${optionName}`)(this)
  }
    }
```

I know that I can test the constructor fairly easily, in this case, but I don't know if it is good way or not.

```js
const CommandOption = require('./command-option')

it('should equal "hardware", "get", and "byid"', () => {
  let commandOption = new CommandOption(['hardware','get','byid'])
      
  expect(commandOption.section).toBe('hardware')
  expect(commandOption.method).toBe('get')
  expect(commandOption.command1).toBe('byid')
}
```

I don't really know how to go about mocking the option method from there... I have read about using `jest.spyOn()` but I can't seem to wrap my head around it for my case... probably because I am trying to overthink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test solution:

`command-option.js`:

```js
class CommandOption {
  constructor(commands) {
    this.section = commands[0];
    this.method = commands[1];
    this.command1 = commands[2];
  }

  option(optionName) {
    return require(`./commands/options/${optionName}`)(this);
  }
}

module.exports = CommandOption;
```

`command-option.test.js`:

```js
const CommandOption = require('./command-option');

describe('64327189', () => {
  it('should equal "hardware", "get", and "byid"', () => {
    let commandOption = new CommandOption(['hardware', 'get', 'byid']);
    expect(commandOption.section).toBe('hardware');
    expect(commandOption.method).toBe('get');
    expect(commandOption.command1).toBe('byid');
  });

  it('should load option by name', () => {
    const optionSetter = jest.fn();
    jest.doMock('./commands/options/host', () => optionSetter);
    let commandOption = new CommandOption(['hardware', 'get', 'byid']);
    const optionName = 'host';
    commandOption.option(optionName);
    expect(optionSetter).toBeCalledWith(commandOption);
  });
});
```

`commands/options/host.js`:

```
// whatever
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64327189/command-option.test.js
  64327189
    ✓ should equal "hardware", "get", and "byid" (4ms)
    ✓ should load option by name (3ms)

-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File               |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files          |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 command-option.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.848s, estimated 10s
```